# wireless drops after using it

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

Recently, I have installed Linux Mint 10 Julia. Everything worked from the beginning (even the external wifi dongle), but I discovered that the wifi connection gets lost after some time. To solve it, I have to disable networking and re-enable it.

Does anybody know what the problem could be? Further details can be found below:

```
iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"myessid"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:22:3F:91:15:89   
          Bit Rate=11 Mb/s   Tx-Power=11 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=512 B   Fragment thr=512 B   
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 00:22:3F:91:15:89
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=51 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"myessid"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000000027bf580
                    Extra: Last beacon: 6484ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00087461636B776C616E
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101820003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C334E101BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A4E101BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C3401051B00000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601051B00000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DD0A00037F04010000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD820050F204104A000110104400010210570001001041000100103B00010310470010565AA94967C14C0EAA8FF349E6F593111021000D4E6574676561722C20496E632E10230007574E523230303010240007574E523230303010420004353637381054000800060050F204000110110007574E5232303030100800020084103C000103
```

The wifi hardware I am using is this:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 07d1:3c09 D-Link System DWA-140 RangeBooster N Adapter(rev.B1) [Ralink RT2870]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1221:3234  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

UPDATE:

When trying to manually install the driver for the wifi, I got this error while compiling that driver:

```
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jean-pierre/Bureaublad/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jean-pierre/Bureaublad/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/tools'
/home/jean-pierre/Bureaublad/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/jean-pierre/Bureaublad/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.31-14-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/jean-pierre/Bureaublad/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.31-14-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/jean-pierre/Bureaublad/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../common/crypt_md5.o
In file included from /home/jean-pierre/Bureaublad/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/include/rt_config.h:92,
                 from /home/jean-pierre/Bureaublad/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../common/crypt_md5.c:28:
/home/jean-pierre/Bureaublad/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/include/mlme.h:1185: error: ‘MAX_LEN_OF_MLME_QUEUE’ undeclared here (not in a function)
make[2]: *** [/home/jean-pierre/Bureaublad/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../common/crypt_md5.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/jean-pierre/Bureaublad/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.31-14-generic'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

This could be because I couldn't update my compiler? While I am connected to the internet (I can access the internet through the browser), the terminal always responds with a 404 not found when trying to apt-get update.

Comment: Could you also post the output of `inxi -n`? You may have to install `inxi` but it's in the repos and worth having.

Comment: Could you try to boot from a **current** Mint Live CD and check if Wifi is working? "Julia" is based on Ubuntu 10.10 and almost three years old - the problem may already be fixed in recent version.

Comment: @terdon Network:    Card Intel 82801BA/BAM/CA/CAM Ethernet Controller driver e100

Comment: Well the problem is that I want to use it on a very old computer (+- 14y with a processor of 850 MHz), so Linux Mint Julia was the first installation that was somewhat smooth. The other version feel too demanding for the computer. I hope that it is possible to solve this wifi problem in this version of Linux.

Comment: @Consec: Did you try the (current) Xfce version of Mint? It dosn't contain a full Gnome desktop, so it has less hardware requirements. I would recommend strongly to use a current distro with security updates instead of an outdated one.

Comment: @tohuwawohu I installed the latest Xfce version of Mint, but now the wireless doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Try to blacklist the module `rt2800usb` by adding the line `blacklist rt2800usb` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. You could also try to use the Windows driver using NdisWrapper. Since it's a Draft-N WLAN dongle, WLAN may be still unstable even if the USB will work. Also, it may be required to compile the required module manually, So, another option may be just to use a more recent WLAN dongle.

Comment: see also [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-install-rt2870-chipset-based-usb-wireless-adapter.html) on compiling and installing a driver for a RT2870 WLAN dongle manually.

Comment: @tohuwawohu thank you for the help. The followed to intallation manual you gave, but got some problems (see updated post).